Can any usage of the assignment operator technically be replaced with the walrus operator surrounded by parentheses?
Say we have this assignment statement:
a = 5

Even though it'd obviously be ugly to do this for no reason, we could technically accomplish the same thing with:
(a := 5)

This still assigns 5 to a, and the value that the walrus operator returns just isn't used.
Are there any cases where this replacement wouldn't work?

I don't use walrus but I think I met one situation when it couldn't work - but I don't remember if it was in lambda, in list comprehensions, in generator or something else. But I think I saw announcement that they will change it in next version. Maybe they already changed it. But I don't remember if I tried to use it with ()

@furas But you can't use an assignment statement in any of those places.

What do you mean with "cases"? What are you talking about in general? The "any usage of the assignment operator" sounds much more broad than that single minimal example you showed.

I think it should work anywhere.

You can have an assignment anywhere that a statement is allowed.
An expression can be used as a statement.
A walrus assignment is an expression.

So both normal and walrus assignment can be used as statements.
There's a special-case restriction that walrus assignments can't be used as top-level statements, which is why you have to put it in parentheses.
I thought there might be a possibility that it couldn't be used in th top-level code of a class, but this works:
class Foo:
    (a := 1)

print(Foo.a) # prints 1

